# Why do these images load twice on screen?

Tags: reactjs, image, lazy-loading

I have a basic list of images in a React app, loaded lazily. Everything works, but when I scroll back up to the top, some images reload twice. It seems the issue comes from the opacity animation. How to fix this? Once the images are loaded, they should stay on screen.

```js
import React, {  useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Picture = styled.img<{ loaded: boolean }>`
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  opacity: ${({ loaded }) => (loaded ? 1 : 0)};
  transition: opacity 1s;
`;

export default function Image({src}) {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);

  return (
      <Picture
        loading="lazy"
        src={error ? "error.png" : src}
        onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
        onError={() => setError(true)}
        loaded={loaded || error}
      />
  );
}
```

Here is a sandbox if you want to check the rendering by yourself: https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-ardinghelli-z7pgv?file=/src/Image.tsx

Thanks!

Comment: I'm checking out your sandbox and everything looks fine to me, no double loading

Comment: When you scroll back up, some images do the opacity animation again.

Comment: I've scrolled up and down several times and once an image loads it never does the animation a 2nd time. Could be a browser related issue, I'm using Chrome v86

Comment: I have the same issue in storybook (on chrome). On firefox, it runs perfectly, on safari, the page freezes.